# Render multiple React components in shorthand if condition

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render multiple React components in a shorthand if, but it doesn't work as expected. This is my source:

```
  render() {

    const isLoggedin = true; 

    return (
      <div>
        { isLoggedin ? 
            <Greeting />
            <LogoutButton /> 
          : <LoginButton />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

If I just use one component, it works (for example remove Greeting):

```
  render() {

    const isLoggedin = true; 

    return (
      <div>
        { isLoggedin ? 
            <LogoutButton /> 
          : <LoginButton />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Is there a way to render both of them?

Comment: What errors do you get? Try wrapping your components in a `<div>` in the example with multiple components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<div> </div>` and put a code block there.

e.g.

```
<div>
<Greeting />
<LogoutButton /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
render() {

  const isLoggedin = true; 

  return (
    <div>
      { isLoggedin ? (
          <Greeting />
          <LogoutButton />
        ) : (
          <LoginButton />
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```